# How to use GNU parallel with data and grep?

Tags: parallel-processing, grep, gnu-parallel

```
admin@admin:~$ grep -F -o 's' <<< "SDSDdsds" 
s
s
admin@admin:~$ echo "SDSDdsds" | grep -F 's'
s
s
admin@admin:~$ parallel grep -F -o 's' <<< "SDSDdsds" 
grep: SDSDdsds: No such file or directory
admin@admin:~$ parallel grep -F -o 's' ::: "SDSDdsds" 
grep: SDSDdsds: No such file or directory
admin@admin:~$ parallel grep -F -o 's' <<< ::: "SDSDdsds" 
grep: SDSDdsds: No such file or directory
grep: :::: No such file or directory
admin@admin:~$ echo "SDSDdsds" | parallel grep -F -o 's'
grep: SDSDdsds: No such file or directory
admin@admin:~$ parallel echo "SDSDdsds" | grep -F -o 's'
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. You are either an expert
parallel: Warning: (in which case: YOU ARE AWESOME!) or maybe you forgot
parallel: Warning: ::: or :::: or -a or to pipe data into parallel. If so
parallel: Warning: consider going through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial
parallel: Warning: Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

How to make this work with grep? Doesn't seem to work correctly with grep. Also problems passing data in other programming languages into GNU parallel when data isn't simple numbers or strings.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you baiting me to say something so you can delete the question, because you are clueless and can't answer basic things about broken GNU parallel and Linux? Yes indeed it all looks good in man, but once you start using it you figure out it can't do the basic tasks of the real world. Real world: unicode, multiline strings, using grep for strings. Then 99% of Linux command fails miserably when we apply real-world.

Comment: Huh? Please click [edit] and start your question with a decent desciption of what you hope to achieve. As it stands, you seem to be saying *"here are some commands that don't work"* rather than *"I'd like to do x, y and z, here's what I tried and here's what didn't work"*.

Comment: I searched the whole internet for this and it can't be that nobody is using this wonderful magical tool and other magical tools as described in the man pages with such tasks that would be very popular among billion examples. Something just isn't right, right? Somebody is pulling us for a ride into wonderland aka something isn't working quite right. But yes, maybe somebody will figure it out, but not like in man pages, some very advanced thing nobody on the internet written down yet. And I know how to use magical Google keywords, Google books, regex search, etc. I can't be discovering miracles.

Comment: It is unclear what you expected would happen by running `parallel echo "SDSDdsds" | grep -F -o 's'`. GNU Parallel cannot parallelize a single input. I will suggest you scroll through https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html until you hit an example that is close to what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Parallel cannot parallelize on a single input.

But let us say you have a 1 GB file that you want to run `grep ATTACACAT` on.

```
parallel --pipepart -a my1gb.file --block -1 grep ATTACACAT
```

This will (on-the-fly) split my1gb.file into 1 file per CPU thread, start `grep ATTACACAT` on each CPU thread, collect the output and serialize this when each `grep` finishes.

If the input is in a variable/string:

```
echo "$var" | parallel --pipe grep 2345672
```

But unless `$var` is really big (>1GB) this is unlikely to give any speedup: GNU Parallel has an overhead of 150 ms startup + 3 ms per job.

Comment: I want to pass a string or a variable to grep through GNU parallel, not a file. That's the problem, that it only reads files through GNU parallel. There seems to be no example of it in any books on the internet, but overall all I find is mostly your examples, examples that don't work with variables or real-world multi-line strings. But that's common for Linux man pages to not work in real-world, which is why people don't write real-world examples of it anywhere in books or on web pages.

Comment: @CuriousPanda As far as I know a string or a variable would be in the order for 100 MB or less. GNU Parallel will not help you here: The overhead will kill the performance for such small data.